# Error in Crontab File

Tags: cron, cron-task

I am trying to run a python `script` every `5` minutes.

I type the following in terminal after doing `crontab -e`

```
*/5****/Users/nishantarora/Documents/cronjob.py      (no spaces at all in between)
```

And this is what I get :

```
crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.TVJ8UDlEMk":1: bad hour
crontab: errors in crontab file, can't install
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you did not place any space anywhere. It becomes then also very difficult do understand your line.

> The format of a cron command is very much the V7 standard, with a number of upward-compatible extensions.  **Each line has five time and date *fields*, followed by a user name if this is the system crontab file,
>          followed by a command**.
>
> **<sub>source: `man 5 crontab`</sub>**

Since they talk about *fields*, it is evident that these must be white-space delimited.

The error you obtain, i.e. *bad hour crontab*, makes sense since you only have a single field which represents the minute field, that field, is a bit ill-formatted. I'm surprised it did not complain about that.

Solution to your problem, add a couple of spaces.

```
 */5 * * * * /Users/nishantarora/Documents/cronjob.py
```

Comment: add a couple of spaces exactly where ?
and if possible, can you please comment your version of the crontab command after adding the spaces ?